# Django get_or_create TypeError: invalid argument

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Skill(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class UserSkills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s | %s' % (self.user, self.skill)
```

When I try and do this:

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='myuser')
>>> s, created = Skill.objects.get_or_create(title='mysql')
>>> type(u)
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
>>> type(s)
<class 'django_myapp.models.Skill'>

>>> userskill, created = UserSkills.objects.get_or_create(skill=s, user=u)
TypeError: 'skill' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

As an aside, I feel that my `UserSkills` model could be superfluous - should it just be a `ManyToMany` field on `Skill` to the `User` model?

### Edit

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/sam/.envs/rs-open-auth/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 149, in create
return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
File "/home/sam/.envs/rs-open-auth/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 414, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "/home/sam/.envs/rs-open-auth/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 415, in __init__
raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
```

Comment: What django version is this?

Comment: Django Version==1.5.4

Comment: Can you please post to whole traceback..

Comment: What happens when you use `get_or_create(skill_id=s.pk, user=u)`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
userskill, created = UserSkills.objects.get_or_create(skill=s, user=u)
```

"s" is previously defined as 'mysql'  ("s" is a string).  However, when creating a new model record that has a foreign key of "skill", "skill" has to be a primary key (i.e. 1, 2, etc...).  You can do this by calling the primary key directly (if the "skill" you just created is the first skill in the Skill's model for example:

```
userskill, created = UserSkills.objects.get_or_create(skill=1, user=u)
```

or you can call the primary key of "s" as so to create the new UserSkills instance:

```
userskill, created = UserSkills.objects.get_or_create(skill=s.pk, user=u)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. I still get `TypeError: 'skill' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. It seems to be the skill attribute which has the problem.

Comment: Have you ran "manage.py syncdb"? and 'skill' is correctly added as a foreign key to the UserSkills table?

Comment: Yes I have and it is.